# Film/Animation content needed for Hons Project in Sound Design..

Tags: project, animation, honours, sound-design

Hi all

I know there are a few previous questions along these lines...but I was wondering if anyone could help / offer advice re suitable content..

I'm in my final year of Music Tech degree and intend to base my major project on sound design for film/animation.  I'm already in the process of researching and contacting film makers and animators to ask nicely if I could possibly use their content.

I've seen the common licence options too - Big Buck Bunny and Elephant's Dream, which might be a fall back option.

Ideally, I'd like to work from a blank canvas, i.e. lesser known/unknown artistic content or animation to really focus from a sound designer's perspective, rather than try and imitate existing interpretations.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction??

I'm new to this forum and a newbie sound designer...

Thanks

Geth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Geth,

I just finished a year in VFS where all grads go through a similar process.

I'd say 95% of the people in the program end up finding their video by deep-diving on Vimeo, searching the archives day after day and just sending out tons of letters. Don't think there's a better way, unless you are in touch with someone who's designing something from the ground up.. it's a lot of hunting.

If you want to guarantee you take a new approach and aren't influenced by the original sound treatment, you could just browse Vimeo with your sound off. You could avoid referencing the original audio for the whole time, or just wait until you've at least finished your first pass of edits. At that point you might find it worth your while to listen back and make sure that moment for moment, you're trying to do it better.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Luca - really appreciate your response.  I've been doing lots of Vimeo research during the last few days and I'm awaiting response from quite a few potential sources.

My brother's a graphic designer/illustrator who's keen on animation/film, so I'm also talking through 'from scratch' concepts with him.

Having found this forum a really excellent resource for my studies, I was keen to throw the question out to those who are very much more in the know than I am.....thanks again

Answer (score 0):

contact an animation course, ask them to pass your message onto students to collaborate? that's what we did.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Edinburgh College of Art](http://www.eca.ac.uk/index.php?id=400) they run a really good course in animation and I'm sure some of the students would be glad of a bespoke sound design for one of their projects.

Comment: Thanks Len / Ed for your input.....yep, in the process of canvassing universities/colleges to see what response I get (plus a few other options as mentioned in my response to Luca above).
Your help is much appreciated....cheers guys.